# VBA - Accessing message box attributes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro that will run a set of other macros at the start of every month. However these 'other' macros contain message boxes that will need to be accepted.

Is there a way for the macro I am writing to accept these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Application.SendKeys ("~")`

Example:

```
Sub test()

Application.SendKeys ("~")
Call message
Range("A1").Value = 1

End Sub


Sub message()
MsgBox "Choose", vbYesNo
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655.aspx).  It is hard to keep the sent keys in sync with the target application.  However in this case I cannot think of alternative solution, that does not involve editing the other marcos.  If you have access to these macros consider refactoring them instead, perhaps by passing a parameter which suppresses Msgboxes. (@Manu I'm not criticizing your answer - in fact I've upvoted it as it does exactly what the OP asks)

Comment: @Manu - thank you for you're fast response. It's does exactly what
 I needed.

Comment: @destination-data I completely understand where you're coming from. I do have access to the code but it's not my code. I was trying to avoid upsetting people lol! Thank you for your response :)